Varying results between quickOSM QGIS plugin vs 'Download OSM data' QGIS processing tool
I am working with the graphic modeller in QGIS to query and process OSM data automatically. The script uses the processing tool 'Download OSM data from a query in an extent' to access the data.
When checking my results against results from the QuickOSM plugin I have noticed that some results vary greatly.
I use the same keys and tags in both methods, yet the quickOSM method returns far more data than the other method (this does not occur for every query, only some)
Is this caused by a slight difference in the API's each tool uses? I am unsure what else could be causing this.
In the below images are the keys used in the processing tool and the quickOSM plugin (I removed a few of the 'golf' keys shown by quickosm and their corresponding values from my processing tool, as these features are not present in my area):



Here is an example of the discrepancy in results between the two methods. Red are those from the processing tool, black are those from the quickOSM plugin. 

you need to give us some actual examples of tags that are present/absent

Hi Ian, do you mean the OSM keys/values? I have included these in an edit
